# Caracteres especiales al recorrer un arreglo dinámico C++

Tags: c++, array, string

Soy un programador novel en C/C++, actualmente estoy viendo todo lo relacionado a la memoria dinámica/estática.

Centrándonos en C++, tengo la siguiente duda:

Cuando quiero recorrer un arreglo dinámico se imprimen caracteres especiales que se salen del tamaño del arreglo. Aquí un ejemplo:

*nota*: *este código no tiene ninguna utilidad, simplemente lo usé como ejemplo para que vean a lo que me refiero*

***Este ejemplo imprime correctamente el contenido del arreglo***

```
char* nombre;
int tamanio = 10;
nombre = new char[tamanio];

for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {
    nombre[i] = 'O';
}

for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {
    std::cout << nombre[i];
}

delete[] nombre;

return 0;
```

***Este ejemplo imprime los caracteres especiales a los que hago referencia***

```
char* nombre;
int tamanio = 10;
nombre = new char[tamanio];

for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {
    nombre[i] = 'O';
}

for (int i = 0; nombre[i]!='\0'; i++) {
    std::cout << nombre[i];
}

delete[] nombre;

return 0;
```

Por que es que en el segundo ejemplo se imprimen estos caracteres especiales?. Busque en internet y veo puro ejemplos de arreglos dinamicos de tipo float, int, etc, pero ningún ejemplo de arreglos dinámicos de tipo "char", por lo que no pude encontrar una respuesta.

[image: En la imagen se ve que ademas de imprimirse el las 'O', también se imprimen los otros signos]

*Soy nuevo en aquí, por lo que mi publicación en algún punto no es correcta pueden informarme*

Answer (score 3):

El problema radica en que ningún momento dejaste un espacio para el caracter nulo.

Por lo tanto, cuando se ejecuta este bucle:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; nombre[i]!='\0'; i++) {
    std::cout << nombre[i];
}
```

Ocurrirá un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer), porque nunca indicas el fin de la cadena.

> > Por que es que en el segundo ejemplo se imprimen estos caracteres especiales?

Imprime esos caracteres basura porque en la posición `10` del *array* no está el caracter nulo, de eso depende poder recorrer la cadena para que tenga un inicio y fin.

**Solución:** Debes dejar un espacio adicional cuando reservas memoria para el *array* de caracteres.

**Ejemplo:**

```cpp
int main()
{
    char* nombre;
    int tamanio = 10;
    //Dejamos un espacio adicional para el caracter nulo
    nombre = new char[tamanio + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) 
        nombre[i] = 'O';

    nombre[tamanio] = '\0';

    printf("Caracter nulo: %d\n", nombre[10]);
    for (int i = 0; nombre[i] != '\0'; i++) 
        std::cout << nombre[i] << std::endl;

    delete[] nombre;
    return 0;
}
```

Ahora el *array* tiene 11 espacios de memoria, solo que el último espacio (el de la posición `10`) es donde estará el caracter nulo.

**Observación:**

Si usas la clase [String](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) de C++, sería más sencillo, porque no necesitas gestionar la memoria ni asignar el caracter nulo manualmente.

**Ejemplo:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int tamanio = 10;
    std::string nombre; 
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) 
        nombre += 'O';

    for (int i = 0; i != nombre.length(); i++) 
        std::cout << nombre[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás asumiento que la asignación de memoria inicializa a cero.  En particular, al asignar un *array* (arreglo/matriz) con una expresión `new`, la memoria queda sin inicializar, lo que quiere decir que puede existir cualquier valor.

Si quieres inicializar un *array* de manera dinámica, puedes usar la [inicialización cero](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), de dos maneras:

```
char* nombre = new char[tamanio]{};
char* nombre = new char[tamanio] = "";
```

Y todos los elementos se (re)llenarán con '\0', que es el valor "cero" para un `char`.

Puedes ver más acerca de inicialización y el uso de la expresión `new` en [inicialización](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Como indica @MrDave1999, habitualmente se asigna un *array* con un elemento extra para poder encontrar el fin de la iteración.

Si conoces el número de elementos *a priori*, puedes usar [`std::array`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), una plantilla de clase que proporciona las operaciones de un contenedor y lo puedes usar con algoritmos.